# Как вырезать из строки название почты с помощью Python?

Tags: python, split, substring

Как вырезать из строки название почты с помощью Python? Нужно оставить только почту. На Java это можно сделать через substring. Как правильно сделать тут?

```
`"email":"example@gmail.com"`
```

Comment: Это json? Может, лучше воспользоваться json-парсером, а не извращаться с вырезанием строк?

Comment: нет, это кусок html.

Comment: В этой строке нет ни одного html-тега, зато есть скобки и кавычки, подозрительно напоминающие json. Почему вы решили, что это html?

Comment: то я так вставил криво

Comment: И тем не менее это всё ещё подозрительно похоже на json, поэтому я крайне рекомендую задуматься вам об использовании json-парсера вместо извращений, которые могут сломаться в любой момент в будущем

Comment: спасибо за совет))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = '859-75-95","email":"example@gmail.com","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"вул.'

text = text.split('"email":"')[1].split('"')[0]
print(text)
```

Просто срезать.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Андрей Мостовенко, пожалуйста.